# How is Energy Distributed within a Electromagnetic Wave?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation

Let $$\hat{H}$$
Denote the full energy of the electromagnetic wave. Now is it right to assume that

$$\hat{H}=\sqrt{2\hat{H}_y^2+\hat{H}_x^2}=\sqrt{2\hat{H}_z^2+\hat{H}_x^2}$$

If not, what is the correct relationship and what would one need to assume?

For a photon $$E=pc$$My second question is can I assume $$\hat{H}=Pc$$ Where $P$ denotes the total momentum of the wave.

Comment: For a TEM wave, is not true that $$\hat{H}_x=\hat{H}_y=\hat{H}_z$$, since there is not component in the propagation direction...

Comment: @Tinchito By TEM I assume you mean a transverse electromagnetic wave. Could you explain why there is no component in the propagation direction?

Comment: Here: http://www.ece.msstate.edu/~donohoe/ece3324notes10.pdf you can find the detailed math. A transverse electromagnetic wave (TEM), or plane wave has components of **E** and **H** only in the plane perpendicular to the propagation direction. The amplitudes of these components vary with distance in the propagation direction, but no vector component in that direction.

Comment: @Tinchito but isn't that to say that a photon has no energy component in the direction of propagation? How is the wave meant to propagate if all this is true?

Comment: You equation is not homogeneous. An expression like $H_y^2+H_x$ does not make sense since you are adding two things of differents physical dimensions. It should be $H_x^2+H_y^2+H_z^2$ because of isotropy.

Comment: For your second question, unfortunately you are trying to define a relativistic quantum Hamiltonian. In order to do this, you have to write $\hat H=c \hat{\vec\alpha}\cdot\hat{\vec p}$, that is the [Dirac equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation).

Comment: @Tom-Tom You have to consider that $$\hat{H}_z=\hat{H}_y$$ So it would make sense as $$\hat{H}=\sqrt{2\hat{H}_y^2+\hat{H}_x}$$ Or $$\hat{H}=\sqrt{2\hat{H}_z^2+\hat{H}_x}$$

Comment: You missed my point. Have a look at the exponents !

Comment: @Tom-Tom I'm sorry (I find typing latex on my phone difficult) $$\hat{H}_x$$ should be $$\hat{H}_x^2$$

Comment: That would correct this minor point. Did you have a look at Dirac equation ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom I will study it but ATM it is difficult for me to do so, I hope we can continue this discussion in an hour or so.

Comment: @Tom-Tom however for the moment could you tell me what the relationship between $$\hat{H}_x$$ (the energy of the EM wave in the direction of propagation) is to $$\hat{H}_y$$ or $$\hat{H}_z$$ (which would respectively be the energy for the electric and magnetic fields or vice versa)?

Comment: Then that would be $H_x=0$.

Comment: @Tom-Tom for me that doesn't make sense, there must be an energy component in the direction of propagation otherwise what is make the wave propagate in that direction? If what you said is for a very specific case please consider the more general one.

Comment: Energy is not a directional physical quantity. What makes the wave propagate in a given direction is *momentum*.

Comment: @Tom-Tom Ok that makes sense. Now what I want to be able to do is split $\hat{H}$ into the three components of momentum, I guess I have to study the Dirac equation before I can do so, right?

Comment: I assume it would look like $$\hat{H}=c(\alpha_1 p_1+\alpha_2 p_2+\alpha_3 p_3)$$

Comment: @Tom-Tom Or maybe would be better to write $$\hat{H}=c(\alpha_1 p_x \mathbf e_x+\alpha_2 p_y \mathbf e_y+\alpha_3 p_z \mathbf e_z)$$

Comment: No, the first expression is better. Remember that energy is scalar, not vectorial.

Comment: @Tom-Tom Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator under "Three dimensions", it suggests $$\hat {p}=p_x \mathbf e_x+p_y \mathbf e_y+p_z \mathbf e_z$$ and from that wikipedia link you posted $$p_1, p_2, p_3$$ are components of the same operator implying it would be better to write what I wrote before this comment.